# How to edit the windows registry entry so that Devkit does not look at the incompletely uninstalled ruby installers in windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, devkit

When running ***ruby dk.rb init*** from C:/Devkit it displays as below

[INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.8.7 at C:/ruby

[INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.9.2 at C:/IRails/Ruby192

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

But no such folder exists in the C Drive. How to remove this from the windows registry.

Answer (score 1):

If DevKit `dk.rb` found those elements in the registry that means Ruby was installed in those folders at some point but either manually removed or relocated.

If you open `dk.rb` you will see the registry keys it uses to locate such information:

`Software\RubyInstaller\MRI` first in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and later in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

You can use `regedit` and look for those keys and remove them entirely.

But I would recommend you first check in *Add and remove programs* inside the Control Panel if Ruby is still installed and if so, removed and install properly.